# DataTable.RejectChanges() and refreshing form textbox controls

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm working on a framework understanding in C#.  I have a form with simple add/edit, save/cancel (and Exit) buttons on a form.  The form has a grid, and a datatable bound to it (data table is a field on the form for scope purposes to remain for duration of the form).

Also on the form are 3 simple textbox controls bound to respective columns in the `DataTable`.  When I scroll the grid, the textbox details automatically refresh... perfect.

I have add / cancel coordination working fine, but failing on edit / cancel.  Failing with respect to the following.

I start the form, grid displays 3 rows (column 1 is a simple "Description").  First row has a value `Test` (so shows the corresponding bound individual textbox control on the form).  I click edit button and can now change the individual textbox (not the datagrid) and change it to `Test changed value`.

So, now, I go to click the "Cancel" button and hope for the following... The grid does NOT get updated with the new value, and the individual textbox control goes back to its original `Test` value.

In the Cancel button, I issue a `MyDataTable.RejectChanges()`, and the grid properly retains the original `Test` value, but the textbox control keeps the `Test changed value` content.  When I have this same `RejectChanges()` call during the add/cancel combination, it all works perfectly.

To simulate a similar during the add/cancel, I am explicitly forcing the grid to the last valid row in the datatable which in-turn updates the textboxes... Apparently, something in the calling / reloading process of the `MyDataGridView.CurrentRow` getting triggered does something I can't see.  Since its an EDIT, I'm not removing a row from the table (temporary from the "Add"), and then rejecting (which removes), and forces a row change via `MyDataGridView.CurrentCell = [0, LastDataRowInDataTable]`.

Any thoughts would be great.

Comment: If you're still interested in finding the answer to this, posting the source for your Add/Edit and Save/Cancel event handlers would help make it clearer what you're trying to do.

Comment: Here's the primary dump from my cancel button

MyTable.RejectChanges();
            
// If we were in add mode, always reset to the LAST
if (CurrentMode == AddMode )
{
  // count is 1-based not zero-based context
  if (MyTable.Rows.Count > 0)
    // focus to the ZERO-BASED row of the table
    MyGrid.Rows[MyTable.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;

  // done, get out
  return;
}

no matter what I did after this, the textboxes would not refresh to the pre-edited value

Answer (score 2):

A similar problem occured to me while trying to update two controls (a `Datetimepicker` and a `Textbox`) after calling `RejectChanges`. It was solved by calling method `ResetCurrentItem()` of the control's `BindingSource`.